# Xcode missing link library C++ not found

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 on el Capitan OSX. I am trying to build a set of example C++ file from this project 
https://github.com/hmartiro/redox/tree/master/examples

I am able to build the library no problems within Xcode. The trouble is a separate example Xcode project which cannot find the library.

I have set my Xcode project with:

Header search path:

```
/Users/x/Documents/cpp/redis-cpp/redox/include
/Users/x/Documents/cpp/hiredis
/usr/local/include
```

This does compile fine but the link fails where it cannot find the library:

```
Library not found for -llibredox_static.a
```

My Xcode project linker settings are:

Library search path:

```
/usr/local/lib 
/Users/quantlabsnet/Documents/cpp/redis-cpp/redox/xcode/Release
```

Other Linker Flags are:

```
-L/Users/quantlabsnet/Documents/cpp/redis-cpp/redox/xcode/Release
-llibredox_static.a
```

Does the client project need to be in the same mode (debug vs release) as how the project library was created? Are there are other tips and tricks I am missing where this library does not get found?

Comment: Where is your `.a` library file actually located? It should just be a matter of simply adding it to your project and including it in `Link Library with Binary`.

Comment: That would help wouldn't? The library a file is located /Users/quantlabsnet/Documents/cpp/redis-cpp/redox/xcode/Release

Comment: Why wouldn't it help? That's the standard way of linking a static library to a binary. Generally if you have your static library in your project then you can just drag it into the Build Phases > Link Library with Binary.

Comment: That was suppose to be sarcasm insulting my self. It seems to be work! Big thanks!

Comment: ahaha I see... you're welcome! :)